# How to disable the default browser tooltip when click on the radio button

Tags: jquery, tooltip

I am using jQuery tootip plugin to display the tooltip. But initially when I click on the radio button label default tooltip(in title attribute) is coming.How to hide the default tooltip?

I have tried blur function and mouseenter and mouseleave function?But none of these are working.

Comment: have you tried removing the `title` attribute?

Comment: can you provide the html for this?

Comment: @MichaelCoxon Tooltip plugin is taking the tooltip value from title attribute.If i remove title attribute how can get the cutomize tolltip?

Comment: The tooltip plugin will have an option to set where the tool tip is read from. Just make it data-tooltip. Can you please post a link to which tooltip plugin you are using.

Comment: @MichaelCoxon: https://jqueryui.com/tooltip/